# How much gas is consumed by a smart contract deployment?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas

I have a compiled EVM file which is 18,012 bytes large and when placed on the blockchain it creates a contract which is `17,859` bytes large. This size has been checked by running

```
eth.getCode(contractAddress);
```

Geth reports that the gas consumed when deploying the contract is `2,156,370`. But the [Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io/) Appendix G Fee Schedule states that the deployment of a contract should be 200 gas per bytes which gives `17,859*200=3,571,800` gas, larger that the `2,156,370` gas reported by geth by running this code:

```
var rcpt = eth.getTransactionReceipt(submittedContract.transactionHash);
console.log('Gas used: ' + rcpt.gasUsed);
```

The deployment of the contract (the constructor) also writes to storage so the gas consumed should be even larger. What am I missing?